# T-SQL and SSRS Grouping and Count

Tags: t-sql

I have to take data from 2 tables and output the data in the form of a Pivot. the data has 3 types of head counts, Actual, Plan and Pending and the headcount number is pivoted with the months. Now I'm able to get a partial solution. The following is my code to get data for Actual headcount.

```
SELECT

' Actual' HC_TYPE, p.[Owner], h1.ProjectID, p.ProjectName, h1.Center,
substring(convert(varchar,h1.Period,120),1,7) Period,
(Case when (substring(h1.ID,1,3) <> 'TBD') then count(*) else '0' end) HC

FROM HC_PLAN_EXPANDED h1, PROJECTS p 

WHERE p.Status = 'Active' 

AND h1.ProjectID = p.ProjectID          

GROUP BY  p.Owner, h1.ProjectID, h1.Center, p.ProjectName,
substring(convert(varchar,h1.Period,120),1,7), h1.ID
```

I need to not use group by h1.ID but be able to use h1.ID in the case condition.

Comment: Adding "Urgent" to the description of your problem is more likely to annoy the community here and have them ignore your question.  Your question isn't any more urgent than anyone else's.

Comment: I'm sorry about that.. But my situation demanded it.. cheers

Comment: I think a nicely stated 'urgency' request can actually produce the desired effect. But hardly so when it is straight in the title, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did..

SELECT a.ProjectID, Center, ID, 
        Period, [Source], p.ProjectName, p.Owner, COUNT(1) AS HC,
         CASE 
         WHEN substring(ID,1,3) <> 'TBD' THEN count(1) 
         ELSE 0
         END AS HC_TYPEA,

```
     CASE 
     WHEN substring(ID,1,3) = 'TBD'  THEN COUNT(1)
     ELSE 0
     END AS HC_TYPEp
```

FROM HC_PLAN_EXPANDED a JOIN PROJECTS p
ON a.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
WHERE p.Status IN ('ACTIVE')
and period between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-01'

GROUP BY a.ProjectID, Center, ID, Period, [Source],  p.ProjectID, p.ProjectName, p.[Owner]

I grouped the 3 types of Headcount on the reports builder.. I know its a lot different from what I actually asked.. but it served my purpose.. thank you all for your support..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
SELECT

' Actual' HC_TYPE, p.[Owner], h1.ProjectID, p.ProjectName, h1.Center,
substring(convert(varchar,h1.Period,120),1,7) Period,
(Select Case when (substring(h1.ID,1,3) <> 'TBD') then count(*) else '0' end from h1) HC

FROM HC_PLAN_EXPANDED h1, PROJECTS p 

WHERE p.Status = 'Active' 

AND h1.ProjectID = p.ProjectID          

GROUP BY  p.Owner, h1.ProjectID, h1.Center, p.ProjectName,
substring(convert(varchar,h1.Period,120),1,7), h1.ID
```

Comment: I tried that but has the same output. When I group by the ID i'm not able to get the count of records with same IDs.. instead it splits the records and shows count as 1 for each record.. I hope i'm making sense..

Comment: Silly me, I  left the same groupings from the original query:) Have you tried this query w/o grouping by h1.ID?

Comment: yes.. I did.. doesn't work..  BTW I took a diff approach.. I found the solution.. thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Nice, congrats. Can you please post the solution? Perhaps another user will run into the same problem. Also, then this question can be marked as answered. Congrats again:)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you say you have already found your solution, you may still want to have a look at this. Just in CASE. :)

```
SELECT

' Actual' HC_TYPE, p.[Owner], h1.ProjectID, p.ProjectName, h1.Center,
substring(convert(varchar,h1.Period,120),1,7) Period,

count(Case substring(h1.ID,1,3) when 'TBD' then null else 1 end) HC  /* <-- */
/* alternatively, and closer to your structuring too:
count(Case when substring(h1.ID,1,3) <> 'TBD' then 1 end) HC
*/

FROM HC_PLAN_EXPANDED h1, PROJECTS p 

WHERE p.Status = 'Active' 

AND h1.ProjectID = p.ProjectID          

GROUP BY  p.Owner, h1.ProjectID, h1.Center, p.ProjectName,
substring(convert(varchar,h1.Period,120),1,7)
```

Comment: This looks promising.. I'll give it a try.. thank you very much!!:)